# Catkin insists on using em.py 3.4 and nosetests 3.4, when configured to use python 2.7

Tags: python, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I call catkin_make like this

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

I see this in the output

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-3.4
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/em.py
```

Naturally my build process fails because the python 2 executable cannot interpret these versions. How do I force catkin to use the python 2.7 versions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192806/catkin-insists-on-using-em.py-3.4-and-nosetests-3.4,-when-configured-to-use-python-2.7/) by [clauniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20215/clauniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating a symboilc link from the 2.7 to 3.4 package helped me. I know this is not a perfect solution,but it works for now.

`ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.py /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/em.py`

Hoping someone with a better knowledge could provide a more concrete solution

---

Originally posted by [marauder](https://answers.ros.org/users/20323/marauder/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clauniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20215/clauniel/) on 2014-10-06**:
This is an option, but it also means you cannot use the 3.4 version for anything else anymore, right?

**Comment by [marauder](https://answers.ros.org/users/20323/marauder/) on 2014-10-12**:
Yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try setting the CMake variable `PYTHON_VERSION` to `2.7` or just `2`. Using `catkin_make` you want to pass `-DPYTHON_VERSION=2.7`.

This will also figure out the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marauder](https://answers.ros.org/users/20323/marauder/) on 2014-10-12**:
The python executable is being detected as the 2.7 version . But the em.py package is using the python 3 version no matter what the cmake variable is being set